# Words are not coming in menu wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

[image]
Please see the image menu words are not coming. I am using wordpress theme enflod.

***The menu words are getting break and hide.***
I am getting this problem 1st time.

Website url http://seoindiarank.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I see your site and those two menu full word are showing in the menu area.

Comment: Sir,If you change your page i mean menu then you can't see it

Comment: Hey can you try to increase your menu area width ? Your problem is it happens when every time page refresh. But when try to hover mouse hover or scroll down/up the rest of the word are came back. I think it's a CSS/jQuery problem. Check your menu CSS or jQuery settings I hope you can figure out and it will be solved

Comment: Thanks sir. I will try

Comment: I have try but not working anything sir